# Unique Triple of Integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you solve for $3$ positive integers that satisfy the following:

> Let $r=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{53}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}}$. There is a unique triple of positive integers($a, b, c$) such that:
> $r^{100}=2r^{98}+14r^{96}+11r^{94}-r^{50}+ar^{46}+br^{44}+cr^{40}$.
> What is the value of $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$?

What

[image]

Comment: [Guide to how to type mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: A good beginning would probably be to divide through by $r^{40}$ and then switching variable to $s=r^2$.

Answer (score 3):

The value of $r$ suggests that $r$ is a root of a quartic equation of the form

$p(x) = ux^4 + vx^2 + w$  (I am trying to stay away from $a,b,c$ to avoid confusion.)

$r = \sqrt {\frac { -w \pm \sqrt {w^2 + 4uw}}{2u}}$

From the given value of $r,$ there is sufficient information to find $u,v,w$

$r$ is a root of $p(x)$ and $r$ is also a root of:

$x^{40}(x^{60} + 2x^{58} + 14 x^{56} + 11 x^{54} - x^{10} + ax^{6} + bx^{4} + c)$

In which case

$x^{40}(x^{60} + 2x^{58} + 14 x^{56} + 11 x^{54} - x^{10} + ax^{6} + bx^{4} + c) = p(x)q(x)$

where $q(x)$ is some as of yet unidentified polynomial.  $q(x)$ will actually prove to be unimportant.  What is important is that you can divide evenly (that is leave no remainder)

Divide $x^{60} + 2x^{58} + 14 x^{56} + 11 x^{54} - x^{10} + ax^{6} + bx^{4} + c$ by $p(x),$ and chose $a,b,c$ such that the remainder is $0.$

Answer (score 0):

That number is nonzero, so dividing by $r^{40}$, the equation becomes
$$r^{60} = 2r^{58}+14r^{56}+11r^{54}-r^{10}+ar^6+br^4+c$$
Now let $s = r^2 = \frac{\sqrt{53}}{2}+\frac{3}{2}$. Then $s$ should satisfy
$$s^{30}=2s^{29}+14s^{28}+11s^{27}-s^5+as^3+bs^2+c$$
$$s^{30} - 2s^{29}-14s^{28}-11s^{27} = -s^5+as^3+bs^2+c$$
$$s^{27}(s^3-2s^2-14s-11) = -s^5+as^3+bs^2+c$$
Notice that $-1$ is a root of the LHS, and so it factors as 
$$s^{27}(s^3-2s^2-14s-11) = -s^5+as^3+bs^2+c$$
$$s^{27}(s+1)(s^2-3s-11) = -s^5+as^3+bs^2+c$$
Using the quadratic formula, $s$ satisfies $s^2-3s-11=0$. Therefore, we have
$$s^5=as^3+bs^2+c$$
Plugging the value of $s$ into both sides and setting the respective coefficients of $\sqrt{53}$ and $1$ equal to each other yields the equations
$$\frac{354}{8}a+\frac{31}{2}b+c = \frac{3543}{2}$$
$$10a+\frac{3}{2}b = \frac{499}{2}$$
Now we just need to find an integer solution to this equation.

Focusing on the last equation, we want $b$ to be odd, and we want $10a$ to be a multiple of $10$. Further, we want $a$ to be a multiple of $8$, so that the first equation will work out. So $10a$ should be a multiple of $80$. Trying various possible values of $a$, it turns out that $b=113$ does the trick, and this gives us $a = 8, c = -334$.